# Randomizing unequal times of each field of a class

Tags: system-verilog

Suppose I have 2 fields in a class, both `rand` or `randc`. But I want one field to randomize once and another field to randomize multiple times. Is it possible?

I have two fields: `addr` and `data`. I wanted to randomize `addr` once and `data` 3 times.  My plan is to as soon as `addr` is randomized once, it should get disabled.  If I do:

```
repeat(3)begin
    s.randomize();
end
```

When it will randomize 2nd and 3rd time, `addr` field shouldn't randomize, but the `data` field should.

But I wasn't able to and I'm stuck on how to do that.  Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you should do is turn off the randomize mode of `addr` in post_randomize

```
class Abhishek;
  rand bit addr;
  rand bit data;
  function void post_randomize;
    addr.rand_mode(0); // off
  endfunction
endclass
```

Since the default rand_mode is 1(on), the first time you call randomize of this class, both members get randomized. The subsequent times you call randomize, `addr` will not get randomized until someone turns it back on.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  There are several ways to conditionally enable/disable randomization for a variable.  Here is one way.

On the 1st call to `randomize`, let it randomize all variables.  On the next 2 calls, only let it randomize `data` by passing it as an argument to `randomize`:

```
module tb;
    class stuff;
        rand bit [3:0] addr, data;
    endclass

    initial begin
        stuff s;
        s = new();
        for (int i=0; i<3; i++) begin
            if (i==0) begin
                s.randomize();
            end else begin
                s.randomize(data);
            end
            $display(" %p", s);
        end
    end
endmodule
```

Sample output:

```
 '{addr:'h9, data:'hc}
 '{addr:'h9, data:'hb}
 '{addr:'h9, data:'ha}
```

Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 18. *Constrained random value generation*